# Fetching json data with struct in Go

Tags: json, go

I am facing a rather simple problem in Go since I am totally new to it. I want to fetch and print data from a REST api. the code I have written:

```
package main

import (
  _"bytes"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http"
)

type Headers struct {
  Headers HttpHeaders `json:"headers"`
}

type HttpHeaders struct {
  Accept string
  Accept_Encoding string `json:"Accept-Encoding"`
  Accept_Language string `json:"Accept-Language"`
  Connection string
  Cookie string
  Host string
  Referer string
  Upgrade_Insecure_Requests bool `json:"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"`
  User_Agent string `json:"User-Agent"`
}


func main() {
  url := "http://httpbin.org/headers"
  res, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer res.Body.Close()

  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  var head Headers
  err = json.Unmarshal(body, &head)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", head)


}
```

After the adjustments I made, the response looks like:

```
{Headers:{Accept: Accept_Encoding:gzip Accept_Language: Connection:close Cookie: Host:httpbin.org Referer: Upgrade_Insecure_Requests:false User_Agent:}}
```

I have still some fields without a value and the value in Upgrade_Insecure_requests does not seem to match the one that is returned via the API.

2nd edit: 
Removed the spaces in the tags. The response now still looks not good.

```
{Headers:{Accept: Accept_Encoding:gzip Accept_Language: Connection:close Cookie: Host:httpbin.org Referer: Upgrade_Insecure_Requests:false User_Agent:Go-http-client/1.1}}
```

The Upgrade_insecure_Requests is still 0 instead of 1 and the other fields are still blank.

Comment: You're doing a lot in your code. At what exact point your expectations don't match the actual variable values?

Comment: The `headers` field isn't exported, and a number of the fields don't match the key names in the json.

Comment: Remove the spaces from your tags please: `json: "User-Agent"` and `json: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"` should be `json:"User-Agent"` and `json:"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"`.

Comment: Also note that underscores in identifiers is considered bad practice in Go (linters will warn you about them). E.g. `Accept_Encoding` should be `AcceptEncoding`, etc. And mkopriva is correct, you cannot have spaces in struct tags (between the tag key and value, nor between comma-separated items in the value).

Comment: You seriously need to read the error messages, if you would, you would know that `"1"` is not a bool but a string in Go, and `json.Unmarshal` will not auto parse a string into a bool so you need to change the type of your field.

Comment: @mkopriva If I use a type of string then nothing appears, seems that parser treats it as nil.

Comment: @vetiv3r it does not treat it as `nil`, most probably your actual code is different from what you've shared in the question  (maybe you have a typo somewhere or something). [with bool](https://play.golang.org/p/AYYTFQb18U) you get error, [with string](https://play.golang.org/p/om6vGHvsle) you get `"1"`.

Comment: @vetiv3r also you should print the `body` to actually see if the header you want was in the response. Do `fmt.Printf("%s", body)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", head)
```

to see all of your fields. As you can see all of strings are empty. It's because in `Headers` struct `headers` field is not exported (first letter must be capital) and no data will be unmarshaled into it. Also some fields name don't match the data in `http://httpbin.org/headers`.

For example change `Accept_Encoding` field in struct as follows:

```
    Accept_Encoding string `json:"Accept-Encoding"`
```

to read from `Accept-Encoding` instead of `Accept_Encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here, first you must export the "HttpHeaders" field of the "Headers" struct, and second, you must tag the fields with JSON names if their JSON key isn't the same (case insensitive):

```
type Headers struct {
  // The "Headers" member must have a capital "H" so that the
  // JSON marshaler knows that it can be de/serialized.
  Headers HttpHeaders
}

type HttpHeaders {
  Accept          string
  // Since the JSON key is the same as the field name we don't need a tag.
  Accept_Encoding string `json:"Accept-Encoding"`
  // Here we need a tag since the member name cannot contain a dash.
  // ...
}
```

Note that the "Headers" field of the "Headers" struct doesn't need a JSON tag because the unmarshaler ignores capitalization when matching JSON document keys to go struct field names. That is, the "Header" field would be populated by the JSON key `"header"`, or `"Header"`, or even `"HEADER"`.

Comment: You do not have to tag them with JSON names if the only difference is case. The tag on `Headers` is unnecessary for unmarshalling.

Comment: @Adrian very cool, I didn't know that! I'll update my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's in the docs for [`Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal): "To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match. Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct."

Comment: Sure enough. Clearly I didn't read docs closely enough the first time around =D